# Does apologizing make me look weak? (how to get referral)

Tags: references

I started a "startup" with a friend.  The reason I did this was mainly because getting a programming job is hard, and the last internship I had programming was somewhat demoralizing; I didn't find the work very purposeful, and didn't want to start heading down a path I found demoralizing.
  Anyway, I had a grand vision for what my business would be, but someone much more experienced and technically competent (call him "Mike") than I am already developed a lot of the technology for it and had his company bought by a giant tech company.  So I spied on Mike's Ph.D students, Fatima and Gautam, pretending I worked for a different big company.
  Turns out it'll probably be easier to work for Mike at that giant tech company than doing this alone; I'll have steady money and get to work with a bunch of smart people who have more experience and skill I do.  Now I want to ask Fatima to recommend me for a job to Mike, but I've lied to her.  My question is just how I should word my request.

#### Here is the e-mail I am considering sending her:

============================================================

Hi Fatima,

I meant to tell you this during the video conference, but I actually lied about working for [big company 1].  I lied because I didn't want you or anyone at Mike's company to know my startup team planned to create a [grand vision for startup idea], but I have since learned that ideas are pretty worthless without the ability to execute them.
  But I'm so excited about making a [grand vision for startup idea] that I would be honored to work for Mike!  That was ultimately the point of the video call; I wanted to ask you to refer me to Mike or someone workin gon
this idea.

-Nick

============================================================

If you were Fatima, would you be more likely to help if I apologized?  Please let me know what other information I can provide to help.

Comment: If you leave a downvote, please tell me why

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Would explaining the situation be better or worse than apologizing?  I'm guessing worse

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Just generally to understand what the big company was doing with that technology.  I wanted to know what chance we had of succeeding

Comment: @platonicity the situation is already not so good TBH, apologizing would hardly make them forget this

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Sorry, yes.  I'm really excited about the potentials for this technology!  I have a Columbia degree in computer science, and I'm a hard worker

Comment: *Apologizing* doesn't make you look weak. Lying and spying on a competitor makes you look weak.

Comment: My view of this doesn't warrant an answer, but I feel you won't get the job any way you look at it. In order not to get a bad reputation from this, just drop it. Don't admit to lying, don't push the matter, and hope it slides. If Mike has friends in the business, it could potentially prevent you from getting other jobs. I hope you learned your lesson.

Comment: Does Fatima even have a reason to refer you? It doesn't seem like she knows you personally or seen any of the work you do. She might not want to risk her reputation to back you in the first place and even then, referred people at Big companies still usually have to go through the hiring process. Enthusiasm is great and all and so is having a degree and being a hard worker but that doesn't make you stand out from the crowd., that makes you part of the crowd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any way this ends without your bridge being burned with all 3 of Mike, Fatima, and Gautam.  I think you are probably never getting this job no matter how hard you try, at least not anywhere in the near future.  That said, currently your chance of getting the job basically amounts to them never asking the "why did you want to leave [big company 1]" question, which is possible but highly unlikely.  If that question comes up you'll have to be prepared to answer it.

The other option, which it sounds like you're leaning towards, is to admit to the lie and pray.  Personally speaking, this would speak negatively to me, as first and foremost, you lied.  That said, it also speaks to a level of maturity that you are admitting to it and humbling yourself rather than trying to BS your way through it.  However, on balance, I think I'm more likely to still think negatively of you even if you apologize.

I think your best shot if you want this job is to come clean, explain the situation in full (as you have done here, except without the redacted parts, and including how enthusiastic you are about this technology), and pray.  However, I think the situation is pretty bleak either way.

One thing I might suggest, though, if the situation permits, would be to go directly to Mike with your apology.  Apologizing to one of Mike's subordinates might not really do much.  In the end, if Mike is the one making the decision, then Mike should be the one you are apologizing to, as it will in the end be his call on whether to forgive you or not.

Comment: I appreciate the relative lack of judgmental-ness; I do actually feel bad about all this.  I agree with your objective analysis; I think getting caught in the lies has backed me into the corner of inventing a whole bunch of other stuff in an attempt to get this job, which I'm definitely not proud of, but if it means maximizing my chances of "success," I'll probably have to go this route.  Anyone else judging me can certainly keep judging me, but at the end of the day I gotta make do with what I've got

Comment: oh ****, but then supposing I get a little further with the BS, it's going to be progressively harder and harder to keep up as I move along in the career, supposing the absolute best case (that I somehow get away with it)

Comment: One thing I thought of is that apologizing to Fatima but not to Mike (or Gautam, for that matter) sounds somewhat conspicuous.  What you did was against the entire company that Fatima was working for, not just Fatima herself.  IMO you should apologize to at least Mike, if not all 3 of them in one large email.  If I was Mike, I'd prefer to hear your apology from the horse's mouth than to hear it second-hand from my subordinate.  My answer has been edited appropriately.

Comment: I only met Fatima and Gautam.  But yes, since Mike is the one with the power to hire, I should probably go directly to him and ask.

Comment: Also, @Ertai87, out of curiosity, how often do you go on this site?  I always wonder who my saviors are :P

Comment: I spend my own downtime at work mostly on this site, and also Skeptics SE and Politics SE.

Answer (score 3):

Apologizing doesn't make you look weak.  However a real apology accepts the consequences, and the consequences of lying means that you probably aren't someone they want to work with.  A better apology would sound more like this:

> Hi Fatima,
>
> I meant to tell you this during the video conference, but I actually lied about working for [big company 1]. I lied because I didn't want you or anyone at Mike's company to know my startup team planned to create a [grand vision for startup idea], but I have since learned that ideas are pretty worthless without the ability to execute them.
>
> I've also learned that lying in order to get a job is counter-productive.  I would be happy to work for Mike, but I know that he's not going to be interested until I've matured and shown that I can be reliable.  Because of that, I would like to apologize to you and Mike.  I will look elsewhere for work and look back on this episode in my life as a learning experience.  I hope that if our paths cross in the future, you will see a person who you would be willing to work with, because of the change I am making now.

Apologizing makes you look strong, if you are willing to accept the consequences and learn from it.  If you try to avoid the consequences (like still trying to get a job there), or don't seem to learn from it (like not realizing that lying is a deal-breaker), then it's not an apology, it's just a 'sorry I got caught'.

If you want to learn this lesson without being caught, then your best bet is to walk away now, with no explanations.  Try to find a job somewhere else, where you won't run across any of these people for some time, so you won't have to make apologies.  (I think that isn't as strong of an action, a real apology will work better in the long run, but others will disagree.  They could be right.)

Comment: It sounds like OP hasn't actually been caught; from the OP it sounds like he wants to work for Mike, but the only way to work for Mike with any sensible excuse (because the "why are you leaving [big company 1]" question is likely to come up) is to first admit to the lie.

Comment: @Ertai87 true.  In this case I guess it's more of a 'sorry there's no way out without being caught.'

Comment: Do you think there's no way I could squeeze in some "I really admire your work and would like to work on this problem with y'all" in there?  It really is a much more interesting problem than most programming problems and my pickings are pretty slim at the moment.  If I'm not going to ask them for work, there's really no point bothering them with an apology, right?  "What you don't know doesn't hurt you" and all